# How to stay in the same tab after showing the search result

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have several tabs in one page,so in the 2nd last tab, I am giving options to user for filtering.After choosing the appropriate filter when I am clicking the search button it is doing the filtering but loads the page with the first tab.Like loading the page for the first time. So my question is, how can I stay in the same tab after hitting the search button. Please suggest me with some example. Here is my code for that particular tab-

```
<div id="requestHistory" class="tab-pane">
         <br/>
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelCRHistory" runat="server" CssClass="row" DefaultButton="btnSearch" UpdateMode="Conditional">
         <ContentTemplate>
         <div class="colmd-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 responsive-filterbar">
               <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drpCRHistoryFramework" ClientIDMode="AutoID" DataTextField="title" DataValueField="frameworkID" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpCRHistoryFramework_SelectedIndexChanged">
               <asp:ListItem  Selected="true" Text ="--Framework--" value="0" ></asp:ListItem>
               </asp:DropDownList>                
         </div>
         <div class="colmd-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 responsive-filterbar">
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drpCRHSkillName" ClientIDMode="AutoID" DataTextField="skillName" DataValueField="skillID" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpCRHSkillName_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Selected ="true" Text ="--Competency Name--" Value ="0"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
         </div>
         <div class="colmd-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 responsive-filterbar">
             <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drpCRHLevel" ClientIDMode="AutoID"  CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" >
            <asp:ListItem Selected ="true" Text ="--Competency Level--" Value ="0"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 responsive-filterbar">
          <div class="input-group">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="canidateRequestHistorySearchTextBox" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="canidateRequestHistorySearchLinkButton" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btncandidateRequestHistorySearch" CssClass="btn btn-primary" CausesValidation="false" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></asp:LinkButton>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div><br /><br />
        <div class="colmd-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 responsive-filterbar input-group date" style="padding-left: 15px;" id="dpDate">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFormDate" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="SingleLine" CssClass="form-control datepicker" placeholder="From Date"></asp:TextBox>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>

            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtToDate" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="SingleLine" CssClass="form-control datepicker" placeholder="To Date"></asp:TextBox>
             <span class="input-group-addon">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
             </span>
         </div>
         <br/><br/>
         </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdCandidateRequestHistory" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        CssClass="table" BorderWidth="0px" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridview-header" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="gridview-alternative"
        GridLines="Horizontal">

        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" CssClass="gridview-alternative" ForeColor="#284775" />

        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <h3 style="float: left;" class="text-warning">There are currently no request history</h3>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>

        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mentor Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID ="lblMentorName" ClientIDMode="Static" Text='<%# Eval("MentorName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Requested Competency">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID ="lblSkillName" ClientIDMode="Static" Text='<%# Eval("skillName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Requested Competency Level">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSkillLevel" ClientIDMode="Static" Text='<%# Eval("levelValue") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sent Date">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSentDate" ClientIDMode="Static" Text='<%# Eval("requestDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus" ClientIDMode="Static" Text='<%# Eval("status") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="cssPager" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" CssClass="gridview-header" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
      </asp:GridView>
     </div>
```

Here is the code behind for the button -

```
protected void btncandidateRequestHistorySearch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        searchQuery = canidateRequestHistorySearchTextBox.Text;

        skillLevel= drpCRHLevel.SelectedValue;
        var candidateRequestHistoryByFiltering = CandidateRequestManager.GetCandidateRequestHistory(((int)Session[CommonHelper.Constants.CURRENT_CANDIDATE]), frameworkID, skillID, null, null, null);
        grdCandidateRequestHistory.DataSource = candidateRequestHistoryByFiltering;
        grdCandidateRequestHistory.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript or jQuery to do this for you, and call the JavaScript from the code behind 
something like this 
JavaScript :

```
function closeWin() {
     document.getElementById("Div").style.display = "block";
}
```

code behind

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "closeWin()", true);
```